# scroll to top when tapping on the active tab in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know there is a hook for that https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-scroll-to-top/ . But at the beginning of my project, i created my own bottom tab component instead of using createBottomTabNavigator(). So i have a code like that `<BottomNavigator selected={'Explore'} />` at the bottom of five screen. I want to scroll to top when active tab tapped. I can understand that if active tab is tapped but i get that information in BottomNavigator component. So i have no idea how to retrieve that information back to current screen and scroll to top.